# invalid multibyte string in foreign language encoding

Tags: r, encoding, topic-modeling, chinese-locale

I am analyzing parsed/segmented foreign language (simplified Chinese) text documents with R's `stm` to leverage the package's plotting environment. I did not use the package's built-in text processing function as it currently does not support handling Chinese text; however, after I successfully prepared the data (which requires `documents` and `vocab` in `lda` format combined with the original meta data of the same row length) and fitted the model, the `plot()` function threw me an error message, plausibly owing to some encoding issues at the preprocessing stage:

```
Error in nchar(text) : invalid multibyte string, element 1
```

Following the suggestion from some previous threads, I applied the encoding functions from [`stringi`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringi/versions/1.4.3/topics/stringi-encoding) and [`utf8`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utf8/versions/1.1.4/topics/utf8_encode) to encode the `vocab` to UTF-8 and re-plot the estimation result again, but it returned the same error. I'm wondering what's going on with the encoding and if such error is fixable because the `stm` uses the base R's plotting function and the latter should have no problem with displaying foreign language text. (note that I have re-set the language locale to "Chinese" ((Simplified)_China.936) before pre-processing the raw text)

It will be really appreciated if someone could enlighten me on this. My code is provided at below.

```css
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Chinese")  # set locale to simplified Chinese to render the text file
# install.packages("stm")
require(stm)

con1 <- url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/tldmo7v9ssuccxn/sample_dat.RData?dl=1")
load(con1)
names(sample_dat)  # sample_dat is the original metadata and is reduced to only 3 columns
con2 <- url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/za2aeg0szt7nssd/blog_lda.RData?dl=1")
load(con2)
names(blog_lda)   # blog_lda is a lda type object consists of documents and vocab

# using the script from stm vignette to prepare the data
out <- prepDocuments(blog_lda$documents, blog_lda$vocab, sample_dat)
docs <- out$documents
vocab <- out$vocab
meta <- out$meta

# estimate a 10-topic model for the ease of exposition
PrevFit <- stm(documents = docs, vocab = vocab, K = 10, prevalence =~ sentiment + s(day), max.em.its = 100, data = meta, init.type = "Spectral")
# model converged at the 65th run
# plot the model
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(PrevFit, type = "summary", xlim = c(0, 1))
Error in nchar(text) : invalid multibyte string, element 1

#check vocab
head(vocab)
# returning some garbled text
[1] "\"�\xf3½\","       "\"���\xfa\xe8�\","
[3] "\"�\xe1\","        "\"\xc8\xcb\","    
[5] "\"\u02f5\","       "\"��\xca\xc7\","
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use

vocab <- iconv(out$vocab)

or

vocab <- iconv(out$vocab, to="UTF-8")

instead